# Initialize a fragment in android before showing it's content

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a simple android app I did mostly for practice. It contains MainActivity and 2 fragments, one with ImageView and second one with Listview. I tried to fill ListView using ArrayAdapter, but currently I'm stuck this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ikurek.pwr, PID: 2792
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.ikurek.pwr.Budynki.onCreateView(Budynki.java:40)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

If I understand correctly, It's caused by my app trying to fill the ListView before the view is even created. I can't figure out how to create the view before my filling function fires. How can I do it?

My MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //Obsługa poszczególych opcji menu
    if (id == R.id.nav_Budynki) {

        Budynki fragment = null;
        fragment = new Budynki().newInstance();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.startScreen, fragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Mapa) {

        Mapa fragment = null;
        fragment = new Mapa().newInstance();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.startScreen, fragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And My ListView fragment code:

```
public class Budynki extends Fragment {

public Budynki() {
}


public static Budynki newInstance() {
    Budynki fragment = new Budynki();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budynki, container, false);
}

public void makeListViewArray()
{
    String[] arrayBudynki ={"A","B","C"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayBudynki);
    ListView lista= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I tried to find the solution myself, but I'm afraid I can't. I tried to call makeListViewArray() in both OnCreate() and OnCreateView(), without any success. Help please :-D

**UPDATE:**

I changed my fragment to :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budynki, container, false);
    // make changes to view and its children here
    String[] arrayBudynki ={"A","B","C"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayBudynki);
    ListView lista= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

And I still get the same error, ideas please?

**UPDATE:**

Budynki.xml fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ikurek.pwr.Budynki">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="496dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

Comment: Which line gives the error in your most recent code?

Comment: I posted full error log in question.

Comment: So which line gives the error?

Comment: Also post `fragment_budynki.xml`.

Comment: ListView lista = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

Comment: Please post the XML layout for your fragment. It is the file named `fragment_budynki.xml`.

Comment: Added in question :-)

Comment: Not related to your crash, but don't do this: `fragment = new Mapa().newInstance();`. Your newInstance() method is static, so you can just do `fragment = Mapa.newInstance();`. Otherwise you allocate two instances and throw one away (the `new Mapa()` is unused).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getView()` returns `null` since you have not yet set the view for the fragment. (You are still in the process of creating it in `onCreateView()`.) Notice that you already have a `View` reference named `view`. In fact, you just inflated the XML layout into this `View` object. Use it instead:

```
ListView lista= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Answer (score 3):

The soonest you can start making changes to the view hierarchy in a fragment is inside onCreateView().  You can follow this pattern:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budynki, container, false);
    // make changes to view and its children here
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I didn't think about changing this function structure :-D It seems to work now :-)

Comment: Okay, I compiled the program just now and it didn't help, post updated.

Comment: Don't use getView() to get a reference to the inflated view heirarchy.  Just use the View that was returned by inflate().  getView() during onCreateView() won't return the view hierarchy until AFTER you return it from onCreateView().

Comment: That did it. App runs and compiles :-)

Comment: Glad to hear.  If you could also accept this answer as the correct one, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `makeListViewArray()` in `onViewCreated()` in your fragment, at that point the view is created (as you probably already figured it out from the method's name)

Also, in your Activity, call `Budynki.newInstance();` instead of `new Budynki().newInstance();`; `newInstace` is a static method, so you don't need to instantiate your class to be able to call it. Same applies for the `Mapa` fragment

Comment: Is the used id (`R.id.listView`) correct? Maybe you can post the `fragment_budynki.xml` as well.